# Rewrite url without hash in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to use Nginx rewrite static file path to strip the hash added for cache busting. The hash is always 10-symbol long. For example,

/min/3rd.party.min.1234567899.js has to become /min/3rd.party.min.js

I have tried this, but it doesn't work (fails at configtest) and also looks way to complicated.

```
location /min/ {
    root /opt/app/public;
    rewrite ^.*(?<=(.))[a-z0-9]{10}[.](?=(js|css))[js|css]$ $1$3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you arrived at your regular expression pattern, but the following seems to work:

```
rewrite "^(.*)\.\w{10}\.(js|css)$" $1.$2 break;
```

Any pattern that contains a brace, must be placed within quotes. Use the `break` suffix to process the rewritten URI within the same location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details, and [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.